# UPDATE table values without knowing column names PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the situation. I just know total number of columns the table `test_table` has but don't know their names(sounds strange but its true). Is there any way I can write UPDATE Query for all column values on basis of some ID(auto-increment primary key)?

To add row in this table, I did following which is working but don't have idea how to do it for UPDATE:

```
$newCols = $_POST['newRowCols'];
$query = "INSERT INTO test_table VALUES "."("."NULL";   
foreach($newCols as $col)
{
$query .= ",'$col'";
}   
$query.=")";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to use mysqli_fetch_fields() on a select to get the fields

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not possible. But you can get the column names using the [`information_schema`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html) database:

```
SELECT 
  `ORDINAL_POSITION`,
  `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.COLUMNS
WHERE
  `TABLE_SCHEMA` = $dbname
AND
  `TABLE_NAME` = $tablename
ORDER BY `ORDINAL_POSITION`
```